# como CARGAR html de una página en div?

Tags: html, ajax, sql

como hago para cargar un html de un div

estoy intentando con esto pero no me  funciona cuando la url es amigable por ejemplo : sitioweb.com/cursos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#content').load("sitioweb.com/cursos");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Tambien como haria para seleccionar un html especifico en esa pagina por ejemplo todo lo que esta adentro de `<div class=contenidopagina> sasddas</div>`

le agradezco sus respuestas

Comment: Has probado con `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.forosdelweb.com/f4/abrir-web-dentro-otra-web-html-974904/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` algo como esto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la etiqueta **`IFRAME`**, te dejo un ejemplo de una **url** quemada y una desde **JQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   const urlPagina = 'https://angellomix.com/blog/mostrar-una-pagina-web-dentro-de-otra-pagina-web/';
   
   // aqui modificamos el SRC del IFRAME
   
   $("#divFrame").attr("src",urlPagina);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Mi pagina</h1>
<br>
<br>
<h2>Pagina con URL quemada</h2>
<br>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<br>
<h2>Pagina con URL desde JQuery</h2>
<br>
<iframe width="100%" height="800" id="divFrame" src="" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Camaliet? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a nuevos privilegios). ¡Mira ¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta? si tienes alguna duda!